# What is happening here in this C++ code?

Tags: c++

Can anyone please explain what is going in this C++ code. It compiles and executes fine on Linux.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main = ( cout << "Hello world!\n", 195 );
```

Comment: Here it compiles, but segfaults.

Comment: Where did you find that code? (I want to stay far, far away from that, whatever it is. This code is nasty.)

Comment: Why would someone vote to close this? Agreed, it is a nasty piece of code and One should not write such code ever, but is that reason enough to vote to close? I see too many Q's just voted to close these days because people don't *like* the Q. Sorry but that is not a valid criteria for closing Q's.

Comment: I actually like the question, it's nasty code but interesting for the answers it's turned up. Out of curiousity @fR0DDy where did you find the code?

Comment: @nicholas-smith I found it here http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=MemberProfile&cr=22689214

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The number "195" is the code of RET instruction on x86.

The C++ compiler (gcc in my case) is unable to recognize that "main" wasn't declared as a function. The compiler only sees that there is the "main" symbol, and presumes that it refers to a function.

The C++ code

```
int main = ( cout << "Hello world!\n", 195 );
```

is initializing a variable at file-scope. This initialization code is executed before the C/C++ environment calls main(), but after it initializes the "cout" variable. The initialization prints "Hello, world!\n", and sets the value of variable "main" to 195. After all initialization is done, the C/C++ environment makes a call to "main". The program returns immediately from this call because we put a RET instruction (code 195) at the address of "main".

Sample GDB output:

```
$ gdb ./a
(gdb) break _fini
Breakpoint 1 at 0x8048704
(gdb) print main
$1 = 0
(gdb) disass &main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0804a0b4 <+0>:     add    %al,(%eax)
   0x0804a0b6 <+2>:     add    %al,(%eax)
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/atom/a 
Hello world!

Breakpoint 1, 0x08048704 in _fini ()
(gdb) print main
$2 = 195
(gdb) disass &main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0804a0b4 <+0>:     ret    
   0x0804a0b5 <+1>:     add    %al,(%eax)
   0x0804a0b7 <+3>:     add    %al,(%eax)
End of assembler dump.
```

Comment: @new123456: on why it *sometimes* work. As said, on OS X it crashes, and the Standard specifies that this is not a valid C++ program.

Comment: Interesting, I thought the data segment and the code segment were separate segments and that it should be forbidden to jump to an address in the data segment. But probably this is not true for all implementations.

Comment: @Giorgio It depends on the CPU and also on how the OS sets up the page permissions.  There are quite a few security holes on x86 which stem from the fact that by default, most x86 OSes set data pages executable as well.  It's only relatively recently that x86 has allowed data pages to NOT be executable.

Comment: @fluffy: Yes, I can imagine what you say. I just find it difficult to imagine a good reason why an OS would set the data segment (or pages in the data segment) executable.

Comment: Backwards compatibility, especially with software that performs JIT (javascript interpreters, older OpenGL implementations, etc.)

Answer (score 39):

It's not a valid C++ program. In fact, it crashes for me on Mac OSX after printing "Hello World".

Disassembly shows `main` is a static variable, and there are initializers for it:

```
global constructors keyed to main:
0000000100000e20    pushq   %rbp
0000000100000e21    movq    %rsp,%rbp
0000000100000e24    movl    $0x0000ffff,%esi
0000000100000e29    movl    $0x00000001,%edi
0000000100000e2e    leave
0000000100000e2f    jmp __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)
```

**Why does it print "Hello World"?**

The reason you see "Hello World" printed out is because it's run during static initialization of `main`, the static integer variable. Static initializers are called before C++ runtime even tries to call `main()`. When it does, it crashes, because `main` isn't a valid function, there is just an integer 195 in the data section of the executable.

Other answers indicate this is a valid `ret` instruction and it runs fine in Linux, but it crashes on OSX, because the section is marked as non-executable by default.

**Why can't a C++ compiler tell that main() isn't a function and stop with linker error?**

`main()` has C linkage, so the linker can't tell the difference between the type of the symbols. In our case, `_main` resides in the data section.

```
start:
0000000100000eac    pushq   $0x00
0000000100000eae    movq    %rsp,%rbp
...
0000000100000c77    callq   _main ; 1000010b0
0000000100000c7c    movl    %eax,%edi
0000000100000c7e    callq   0x100000e16 ; symbol stub for: _exit
0000000100000c83    hlt
...
; the text section ends at 100000deb
```

Comment: There are [places on the web](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/qnighy/20090418/1240064403) that claim this is supposed to work on IA32 architectures because `195` is `0xC3`, i.e. the `RET` instruction. Still looks weird to me, though...

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi The link you give claims it is supposed to work in C, not C++.  Still, it's illegal in both languages, for slightly different reasons.  In both languages, you are **required** to define a global function `main`, returning `int`, and taking one of an implementation defined set of arguments.  Any other definition for `main` is illegal (and should cause a good compiler to complain, especially in the case of C++, where `main` must be specially treated anyway).

Comment: @James, I totally agree that code is completely illegal. What I'm finding weird is that apparently some compilers blindly emit a `CALL` to `main`'s address even if it's not a function.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: in cases where a blind call is emitted, it's probably emitted by the linker rather than the compiler proper. Linkers can be pretty blind.

Comment: In my opinion, the disassembly "global constructors keyed to main" does not prove anything. It is unrelated to the problem at hand.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi One of the particularities of `main` in C++ is that the compiler won't mangle its name.  It can't, because the reference in `crt0` (or whatever the system calls its start-up function) was compiled as a C program, and it can't because unlike other functions, `main` can be declared with different argument lists, and still refer to the same function.  And without mangling, there's nothing to tell the linker that `main` is a function.

Comment: @Atom, it is doesn't prove anything, but it's most certainly related.

Answer (score 5):

It's not a legal program, but I think the standard is a little ambiguous as to whether a diagnostic is required or it is undefined behavior.  (From a quality of implementation point of view, I'd expect a diagnostic.)

Comment: Regarding QOI: possibly in cases where the implementation supports a freestanding environment, the compiler proper can't actually tell what environment the object file is destined for (even if the TU includes headers not guaranteed to be present freestanding, the implementation is allowed to provide them). And then the linker can't tell whether the symbol is a function or not. I'm speculating though, I don't know enough about the compiler innards to say for sure what the compiler "should" know about hosted vs. freestanding.

Comment: @SteveJessop If your compiling for a freestanding environment, of course, it's all implementation defined.  But the compiler should know this (since it has to know whether to treat `main` specially or not), and if it is treating the function `main` specially (no mangling, etc.) in order for it to be called from `crt0`, then it knows that `main` in global namespace is special, and can generate an error for the sample code.

Answer (score 1):

It will set the global variable `main` (an integer) to the value of 195 after printing out *Hello world*. You will still need to define the function main for it to execute.

Comment: And if you define the function main, you have undefined behavior (because of the ODR).